# SOLR post json file Default fieldtype

Tags: json, solr, data-import

I have POSTAL_CODE field in my json file. If I try importing that data to SOLR using solr/post, the fieldtype is being set as 'plongs' which is not suitable for data like "108-0023". Beacause of that the data import is throwing out an error. Is there any work around for this kind of issues?

Edit:
Sample data which you might use to check it.

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "POSTAL_CODE": "1982"
},
{
  "id": "2",
  "POSTAL_CODE": "1947"
},
{
  "id": "3",
  "POSTAL_CODE": "19473"
},
{
  "id": "4",
  "POSTAL_CODE": "19471"
},
{
  "id": "5",
  "POSTAL_CODE": "1947-123"
}
```

In the above sample, I don't understand why 'id' is not being considered as 'plongs' or 'pints' but only 'POSTAL_CODE' has that issue. if the first element has POSTAL_CODE as, say "1947-145" then the field type is being taken as 'text_general'. Generally if the value has double quotes, (i.e., "Data": "123") shouldn't it be considered as a string value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the collection, create it as new and before you index anything, define a field POSTAL_CODE in your schema as type string. This will then index any incoming data on this field without guessing, but instead use the string type, which means it is indexed as-is.

Copied and adapted from https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/schema-api.html, but untested:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
  "add-field":{
     "name":"POSTAL_CODE",
     "type":"string",
     "stored":true }
}' http://localhost:8983/solr/yourcollectionhere/schema
```

Comment: Is this the only way. Because there might be many fields for which such issues can be faced. What you said is correct, define the field before indexing. But, is there any other way this can be solved?

Comment: You should always define your schema explicitly for production use. The schemaless mode is fine for experimenting and rapid development, but when you're going to use something in production, the schema should be explicitly defined. Otherwise you can run into issues like this.

Comment: Oh. Ok, that makes sense. So, no shortcuts in importing data. Define everything in the schema beforehand to avoid issues like this. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to import the data by creating a raw json document with the field POSTAL_CODE. Below is my json & my solr version is 7.2.1

```
{"array": [1,2,3],"boolean": true,"color": "#82b92c","null": null,"number": 123,"POSTAL_CODE": "108-0023"}
```

It is indexed as Text Field in solr below is the attached screenshot. Command I triggered to index the data is as below:

```
bin/post -c gettingstarted test.json
```

[image]

Could you please provide the sample data and version of solr on which you are facing this issue.

Comment: The reason why you're seeing a different behavior is because you're _only_ indexing the content with the dash. If you first index a document where the content is a regular integer, it'll be defined as a plong instead. In schemaless mode, the first time a field is used, Solr guesses its field type based on the content.

Comment: Yeah, only thing I wondered is how dash is being removed and generating the concatenated number which solr is then assuming as longs

Comment: I guess few of the entries don't have that dash and those reaches solr first and solr creates it as plongs and latter when dash entry comes to indexing then it complain about it.

Comment: @sriharshay I hope now you know what was the issue, let me summarize it for you. Since solr schema in your case is managed schema this does create the field by regex etc if you don't provide the schema explicitly. So postal_code field first documents once reach to solr, it was numeric so solr assign it as long. But when it sees your last document which is having - in it then it complains about field and giving the error. So as Harald mentioned please define the schema of that field and does the reindexing after the cleanup.

Comment: @sriharshay The reason you are seeing I'd as string field, because if you go in managed schema id field will be predefined as string field and configured as unique-key.  e.g. <field name="id" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>

Comment: @AmanTandon Yeah, all that will be updated in the managed-schema right. I now understood how the POST tool is working. Now, if the data in the JSON, is of integer format when the tool first encounters it, it blindly assumes that field is of INTEGER type. Yeah, and thanks for giving the explanation about how ID is not being assumed as INTEGER.